# UICollectionView inside UITableViewCell how pass data to Uicollectionviewcell

Tags: swift

I have a tableview controller with a collectionview inside it , in the tableviewcell i implemented a collection view with horizontal scrolling, the data appears not correct

```
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = friendsCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "friends", for: indexPath) as! friendCollectioncell
    friendsCollectionView.delegate = self
    friendsCollectionView.dataSource = self

    let ava = Myfriends[indexPath.item]["ava"] as! String
    let firstname = Myfriends[indexPath.row]["firstName"] as! String
    let lastname = Myfriends[indexPath.row]["lastName"] as! String


    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return Myfriends.count
   }
```

problem is in 
    return Myfriends.count
always empty so not thing appears but if a change to 1 or 2. it works ok

in uitableviewcontroller:

```
var myFriends: [Dictionary<String, Any>] = []
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // section 1 which includes 1 cell that shows my friends
    if indexPath.section == 0 {

        // accessing cell in main.storyboard that has id "friends". This cell stores my friends
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "friends", for: indexPath) as! friends



        cell.Myfriends = myFriends


       }


        return cell

        // section 2 (or any other sections) that shows all the posts of the user
    } else {
return cell 
}
```

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**
If I understand this right:

> problem is in return Myfriends.count always empty so not thing appears but if a change to 1 or 2. it works ok

probably your `collectionView(_:numberOfItemsInSection:)` is called before you this `cell.Myfriends = myFriends` is set.

In your friends tableViewCell:

```
class friends: UITableViewCell .. {
    ...
    var Myfriends: [Friend] {
        didSet {
            friendsCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

---

Imho your `collectionView(_:numberOfItemsInSection:)` isn't called at all.
This code

```
friendsCollectionView.delegate = self
friendsCollectionView.dataSource = self
```

in your `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` is useless, because if this method is called, dataSource (and probably delegate) are already set correctly.
Instead, change your tableView(_:cellForRowAt:) to

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell = tableView...

        cell.friendsCollectionView.delegate = cell
        cell.friendsCollectionView.dataSource = cell

        return cell
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

or set friendsCollectionView dataSource and delegate in your **friends** cell, where you init your collectionView.

If that shouldn't help you, check where and how you populate your myFriends dictionary.

---

Besides that, I'd recommend that you create a struct Friend:

```
struct Friend {
    let ava: String
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
}
```

and change your `var myFriends` to
`var myFriends: [Friend] = []`

That would make it easier and safer to access the values for your friendsCollectionCell:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = friendsCollectionView...

    let friend = MyFriends[indexPath.item]
    let ava = friend.ava
    ...

    return cell
}
```